# Are my edits to this C question enough to reopen it?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

My question is closed and I understand the reason why, but I edited the question and improved it, and didn't get any feedback!

I know the moderators are really busy, but how can I get my question reopened?

I also can change the whole question as I have a new programming issue now, which is I guess clear and has the enough required details.

This is my post: [how to reference and dereference a pointer with offset to array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66833211/how-to-reference-and-dereference-a-pointer-with-offset-to-array)

Comment: Cross-site FAQ dupe: [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415/571958)

Comment: If you edited the question than it will be sent to the reopen queue for users to evaluate it. No moderators are necessary in this process

Comment: The question is in the reopen queue, it just hasn't been seen by enough people yet.

Comment: How long this should take ? Because it's been like 1 month. I don't know what is the time procedure in question reopening, should take 2 , 3 weeks, or months. How do I know ? Is it time dependent ? Or what exactly ?

Comment: It requires 3 people to do the review. It takes as long as it takes for that to happen. There are 2,200 questions in the review queue at the moment.

Comment: OK, understood. But the problem is that I can't post any question now ! As I have a new programming issue which I think it's a good one, it's clear, and working, there's just a small issue with the execution of the code. This forum is really good for getting answers and experiences.

Comment: Also, I solved the problem in the closed question, and I'm ready to post the answer but I can't ! I think the closing feature isn't totally wrong, but it strict my actions to do anything about it, all I can is to edit and wait for members review for unknown time limit.

Comment: You commented on your question: _OK, problem solved, I tested the code on my arduino board and it worked, I just have to pass the pointer to the function and the function does the rest._ This sounds as if your question "was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers." This is another close reason...

Comment: @R1S8K - What does your question ban have to do with reopening the question your asking about?  You won’t be able to ask your new question in the body of your existing question (the community will just roll the edit back).  We are also NOT a forum.

Comment: @SecurityHound, yes, I think I'm not getting the full idea of what Stack overflow is. I know that I can get help in this site, I know some of the rules, and I'm not totally new. I've asked some questions, that I won't claim them as GOOD, but I got normal answers and comments on them. And I got better than before and my questions in my opinion are more developed for my programming level, which is what I'm confused about. I'm thinking I should level up here, and not stuck in posting quality problems. It's just strange to me how things got more strict on me recently in this site.

Comment: @honk yes, I think it might be that there isn't much I can do right now to solve my ban problem and post a new question. But I'm trying my best, maybe I can do something.

Comment: @R1S8K - If your deleted questions actually received literal answers, then those questions must have been low enough quality, cause typically questions with answers are not deleted.

Comment: Changing an existing question, like you have done, likely resulted in the downvotes that were the final straw.  You should always make sure you don't ask a question caused by a typo, making sure something compiles, is always a good idea.  **This is evident by the answer Allan Wind provided to your linked question.**

Comment: @SecurityHound yes, I really appreciate your thorough checking my problem, Yes, I got new downvotes ! Which isn't really pleasant. It's OK I'm really happy for all this support until now in this thread, I feel really appreciated and that you all appreciate that I have a little idea of the questions/codes I've posted. My hopes are lifted up because of all the comments and answers in this thread. And it's OK for the ban and the downvotes, I can carry on my programming until I know what to do in this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you edit a post after it gets closed it ends up in re-open review queue which is performed by high rep users, not moderators. I guess they found no reason to re-open it so it remained closed.

Looking at your original question, it was a bit unclear what problem you were trying to solve which I guess is why it got closed to begin with.

Someone pointed out a few simple mistakes in an answer, after which you edited the question to fix those problems. *Don't do that!* You've now rendered that answer senseless - you shouldn't make edits that renders posted answers obsolete. Ask a new question instead, with the changes integrated.

And since then you've done even more radical changes to the question again. This isn't fair to the person who posted the original answer. This is where we would typically rollback your changes. However, the question is now closed so there's no point in polishing it unless it gets re-opened. And a rollback would bring it back to the previous state. So I think the question should remain closed since we can't salvage it, because it has an answer and you made radical edits after that.

What you can do is to copy the contents of this question and ask a new question. However, you need to clarify:

- What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this strange code? Are you trying to create a home-brewed multi-thread system, some type-generic programming, some position-independent code or what?
- You are using non-standard extensions, so clarify which compiler and system you are using. It appears to be gcc and in case it is running on Arduino, you aren't actually using C but C++, which makes a big difference.

Unrelated to your question, this whole code is completely senseless on an 8-bit bare metal microcontroller embedded system. Such systems shouldn't use heap allocation, multi-threading nor should they return from main(). If your intended target is Arduino, I would strongly recommend to forget the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful and thoughtful answer. You got the procedures I did to edit the post and efforts for reopening it. Also, my mistake of getting the mistakes of the question and fixing the issues and putting other answers senseless. You mentioned this to do instead **Ask a new question instead, with the changes integrated.** but how to do that when I'm banned of asking new questions ?

Comment: I have questions to your 2 points.

**First point:** What you mean by:
1. home-brewed multi-thread system
2. some type-generic programming
3. some position-independent code

What do these terms mean ? I try to write code but I don't know which area I'm working in. How to determine in which category of the those 3 types I'm working in ?

Comment: **Second point:** Arduino accepts both C and C++, the file type is `.cpp` but it runs C code with no problems. But in the latest edit, I removed the non-standard extensions, and the code is done on desktop compiler.

Comment: @R1S8K This is not the place to ask follow up questions about your question in main.

Comment: And regarding being question banned, please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/1426539), if you haven't. @R1S8K

Comment: I really like your points of criticizing my work, also I like to know why the code is senseless on **8-bit bare metal microcontroller** ? What to do instead for multitasking on multithreading on Arduino platform ? Because there're a lot of source codes on GitHub about multitasking on multithreading on Arduino, that's why I'm learning from those source files.

Comment: "_I guess they found no reason to re-open it so it remained closed._" [The post is still in the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/28628484).

Comment: @Ivar Thank you so much man for the link :) surprisingly I got 0 votes of 40 ! Now what I want is that I need help to improve my question and fix the problems with it. The link you provided is very helpful, there're the times I edited the post and what I did exactly. But now I need a way to find members that help me to fix the problem. Thanks again,

Comment: @R1S8K: 1) You can get far with [cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking#Usage) on those systems. 2) Perhaps that code is geared towards STM32-based Arduinos (more hardware resources)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks man for helping ! I have question for your point #1, how can I get far with cooperative multitasking ? for #2, I'm doing it for 8-bit microcontrollers, but I think for ported board like STM32, it should work too with some tweaks in the code; if needed.

Comment: @R1S8K: Let us move it to chat.

Comment: @PeterMortensen OK, got your point, I read the Wiki page, yes Cooperative multitasking is suited for embedded systems, that's why I like my code and I know it's OK for embedded systems, NOT perfect of course, but it should work OK for my level in programming microcontrollers.

Comment: @R1S8K I'm not certain of the mechanics involved in lifting a ban, though I would think the ban is only temporary?

Comment: @R1S8K By home-brewed multi-threaded system I mean re-inventing the wheel instead of using something like RTOS. There's also a lib called "protothreads" for microcontroller that iirc don't use different thread stacks. But these are all completely senseless solutions for a 8 bit low end MCU like AVR. If you actually need the level of complexity that comes with multi-processing, you should be using at least ARM Cortex M0, mid- to high end microcontrollers. ruck.

Comment: "there're a lot of source codes on GitHub" Yeah there's lot of senseless code on Github and a lot of clueless people using Arduino. The people who made such libs were likely confused PC programmers.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you so much for your time to answer my comments :) I really appreciate your evaluation for suggested mid- to high end microcontrollers; like, the ARM Cortex M0 which I have, but my goal actually is to get the most of these 8-bit microcontrollers for small college projects. For me personally, I'm leaving working with 32-bit microcontrollers when I think I got the most of Arduino; so when jumping to the higher level MCUs, I should notice the jump in performance.

Comment: @Lundin - Question bans cannot be lifted by anyone.  Only the author through submitting high quality questions can that happen.  The author can submit a new question every 6 months.  The author for your information is question banned, this means they showed a pattern of asking enough low quality questions, and ignored the warning once they were near the threshold.

Comment: @SecurityHound Obviously you _can't_ lift your question ban by submitting high quality questions... but what about answers? I recall something about positive answers and/or rep helping their case.

Comment: @Lundin while question banned you can post a new question each six months until the ban is lifted. So you **can** get out of a ban by posting new questions.

Comment: @Lundin - Except you can; you might read my entire comment

Comment: Yes I read that but waiting 6 months is kind of unreasonable.

Comment: Yes, 6 months is too much, this is the second time I get question ban ! This is actually my first question after the first ban, and when I posted this question I got banned immediately ! That's really rough, I'm trying to learn, I'm not expert programmer. Also, I tried to edit the question and waited for any feedback, but didn't get any. I know I lacked read the post of **How to ask the perfect question**, but also I think I put enough details in my question, and I can edit it more, and that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @R1S8K - You don't have to ask the perfect question just a question that is high enough quality NOT to get deleted by the community or downvoted.  It's not hard to ask a high quality question, there is guidance that exist, we will have to disagree that 6 months is unreasonable amount of time.   In the end there is **nothing** that can be done except increase the quality of your past questions until you can ask that new question.  **The question ban cannot be lifted by anyone.**

Comment: @SecurityHound OK, that's is the only solution obviously, thank you for support. I should work hard on the previous questions for now :)

Comment: @R1S8K - This literal meta question shouldn't have counted towards your single question you were allowed to ask on SO.  Your question has grammatical errors fixing those would go a long way.  Since this wasn't your first question ban, then my theory is slightly off, but the question you linked to certainly didn't help the situation

Comment: @SecurityHound I'm sorry I didn't understand your comment very clear, what you mean ? You are saying that "This literal meta question shouldn't have counted towards your single question you were allowed to ask on SO", what does it mean ?

Also the rest of points, "Your question has grammatical errors fixing those would go a long way", you mean this question has grammatical errors, which ones ? you mean my English has constant errors in my comments, post ... etc. ?

Comment: @R1S8K You could try to polish old, down-voted questions. I took the liberty to clean up this old one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577159/passing-array-pointer-as-a-parameter). Seemed like a decent question. I can post a little answer to it as well, in case that helps.

Comment: @R1S8K - The question you linked to has grammatical errors.  You indicated this in a previous comment, "when I posted this question I got banned immediately !", I was indicating that this literal question on meta.stackoverflow.com shouldn't have triggered an additional 6 months waiting period and it was your question in March that was actually the cause.  Comments do not count towards or against your question ban, if anyone refers to something about grammar, they are likely referring to errors in your actual contributions that can be voted upvoted or downvoted.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks man ! I'm really happy with your help, and I just now, did small improvements in that question, I hope it's better now.

Comment: @R1S8K Yeah well, you haven't really been listening to anything I've said... because I posted an answer quoting parts of your question, then _again_ you edit the question to something else even though there are answers posted. This seems like a lost cause, I'm done here.

Comment: @Lundin wow, I'm really sorry I didn't notice your answer. I thought you only upvoted the post, you're right, I didn't really read the rest of your comment. When you said "You could try to polish old", I thought you mean I can now start polishing my downvotes posts and you upvoted it for me as a motivation, I'm sorry that's how I thought it was. Thanks again for your generous time :)

Comment: @Lundin Can you rollback the post or even can I ?

Comment: @R1S8K I did a rollback. You can do so on your own posts too, if you click on the bottom of it where it says "edited by...". Then you get the edit history. From there you can do a rollback to a previous version.

Comment: @Lundin Man I don't know what to say, you've been really patient with me, I really appreciate it !

Comment: I edited the post linked in the main thread. Hope to get suggestions or recommendations for it.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thank you so much for revising my previous questions man. I got a lot of support in this thread. I'm really happy and you guys really lift up my hopes in this site, I'm currently working on coroutines.

Comment: I got unblocked pretty soon :)
This time is much more sooner than before I guess.
Thanks to Mr @Lundin who helped me a lot improving my other questions and upvoting then and also do some edits too.

So thank you very much I really appreciate your help !